# Unrecognized compile error building application with mysqlcppconn8 library

Tags: cmake, c++17, ubuntu-20.04

I am using vscode's Remote-SSH extension to SSH into AWS Ubuntu 20.04 server where the source codes are located. I am creating an application in C++ that needs to connect to MySQL using `xDevAPI`. I've installed the dev libraries using these steps:

`sudo apt install libmysqlclient-dev libmysqlcppconn-dev`

My compiler version is `gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-6ubuntu2) 7.5.0` && `g++ (Ubuntu 7.5.0-6ubuntu2) 7.5.0`

I've included in the top CMakeLists.txt file

```bash
set(MYSQL_CPPCONN_DIR "/usr/include/mysql-cppconn-8")

find_library(MYSQL_CLIENT_LIB mysqlclient)# "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu")
find_library(MYSQL_CPPCONN_LIB mysqlcppconn)# "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu")
find_library(MYSQL_CPPCONN8_LIB mysqlcppconn8)# "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu")
```

and subdirectory CMakeLists.txt as:

```bash
add_executable(${TARGET_NAME} main.cpp DBServer.cpp)

set_target_properties(${TARGET_NAME} PROPERTIES
                        CXX_STANDARD 17
                        CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON
                        CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)
target_include_directories(${TARGET_NAME} PUBLIC "./include" ${MYSQL_CPPCONN_DIR})
target_link_libraries(${TARGET_NAME} PRIVATE sys core ${MYSQL_CLIENT_LIB} ${MYSQL_CPPCONN_LIB} ${MYSQL_CPPCONN8_LIB})
```

While compiling with [CMake Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cmake-tools) extension, I'm receiving following errors:
[compile error in vscode for mysqlcppconn8 library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSGor.png)

I tried building MySQLCppConn library from [source - github](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-cpp) instead of apt repository, but still received the same error.

Tried in new EC2 instance as well to no success. I've noticed this error after using nested namespace feature of C++17 e.g. `namespace A::B::C` and I think it might have activated the /std:c++latest. Even after reverting back to normal namespace, I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After scratching my head for 2 days. I found out that there is some ambiguity/conflict issue with [evpp](https://github.com/Qihoo360/evpp) library headers.

I've simply included the `<evpp/...>` headers after including the MySQLCppConn libraries and all the compile errors are gone and the application is compiled successfully.

```cpp
#include <evpp/tcp_client.h>
#include <evpp/tcp_conn.h>
#include <evpp/buffer.h>
#include <mysql/jdbc.h>
#include <mysqlx/xdevapi.h>
```

**Changed to**

```cpp
#include <mysql/jdbc.h>
#include <mysqlx/xdevapi.h>
//! Include evpp header files at the end because of some ambiguity error in library
#include <evpp/tcp_client.h>
#include <evpp/tcp_conn.h>
#include <evpp/buffer.h>
```